# change the color of canvas animation

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to change the color of an animation drawn on htm5 canvas. Since the background image behind the canvas is dark color so I need the color of animation to be white. I can't change it's color from greyish to pure white. How can I do that?

```
The html:

<div id="large-header" class="large-header" style="height: 900px;">
    <canvas id="demo-canvas" width="1245" height="900"></canvas>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
canvas {
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.large-header {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
z-index: 1;
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
(function() {

var width, height, largeHeader, canvas, ctx, points, target, animateHeader = true;

// Main
initHeader();
initAnimation();
addListeners();

function initHeader() {
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
    target = {x: width/2, y: height/2};

    largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
    largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

    canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // create points
    points = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < width; x = x + width/20) {
        for(var y = 0; y < height; y = y + height/20) {
            var px = x + Math.random()*width/20;
            var py = y + Math.random()*height/20;
            var p = {x: px, originX: px, y: py, originY: py };
            points.push(p);
        }
    }

    // for each point find the 5 closest points
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var closest = [];
        var p1 = points[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
            var p2 = points[j]
            if(!(p1 == p2)) {
                var placed = false;
                for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                    if(!placed) {
                        if(closest[k] == undefined) {
                            closest[k] = p2;
                            placed = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                    if(!placed) {
                        if(getDistance(p1, p2) < getDistance(p1, closest[k])) {
                            closest[k] = p2;
                            placed = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        p1.closest = closest;
    }

    // assign a circle to each point
    for(var i in points) {
        var c = new Circle(points[i], 2+Math.random()*2, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)');
        points[i].circle = c;
    }
}

// Event handling
function addListeners() {
    if(!('ontouchstart' in window)) {
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCheck);
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
}

function mouseMove(e) {
    var posx = posy = 0;
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
        posx = e.pageX;
        posy = e.pageY;
    }
    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
        posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    target.x = posx;
    target.y = posy;
}

function scrollCheck() {
    if(document.body.scrollTop > height) animateHeader = false;
    else animateHeader = true;
}

function resize() {
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
    largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
}

// animation
function initAnimation() {
    animate();
    for(var i in points) {
        shiftPoint(points[i]);
    }
}

function animate() {
    if(animateHeader) {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
        for(var i in points) {
            // detect points in range
            if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 4000) {
                points[i].active = 0.3;
                points[i].circle.active = 0.6;
            } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 20000) {
                points[i].active = 0.1;
                points[i].circle.active = 0.3;
            } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 40000) {
                points[i].active = 0.02;
                points[i].circle.active = 0.1;
            } else {
                points[i].active = 0;
                points[i].circle.active = 0;
            }

            drawLines(points[i]);
            points[i].circle.draw();
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function shiftPoint(p) {
    TweenLite.to(p, 1+1*Math.random(), {x:p.originX-50+Math.random()*100,
        y: p.originY-50+Math.random()*100, ease:Circ.easeInOut,
        onComplete: function() {
            shiftPoint(p);
        }});
}

// Canvas manipulation
function drawLines(p) {
    if(!p.active) return;
    for(var i in p.closest) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
        ctx.lineTo(p.closest[i].x, p.closest[i].y);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(156,217,249,'+ p.active+')';
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

function Circle(pos,rad,color) {
    var _this = this;

    // constructor
    (function() {
        _this.pos = pos || null;
        _this.radius = rad || null;
        _this.color = color || null;
    })();

    this.draw = function() {
        if(!_this.active) return;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(_this.pos.x, _this.pos.y, _this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(156,217,249,'+ _this.active+')';
        ctx.fill();
    };
}

// Util
function getDistance(p1, p2) {
    return Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2);
}
})();
```

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. Do you want to progressively change the color from grey to white ?

Comment: I am guessing you need a 3rd party's code fixed as to suit your need. You should first direct you requirements to the codes author. If you just want the colours change search the code for rgb and change the colour values to what you need. There are only 2 colours set

Comment: I just simply want the color of animation to black. No progressive change or anything.